# Perl: How to exit from main script if exit criteria is in a subscript?

Tags: perl, exit-code

I have a script *main.pl* which contains a loop over a list. This loop calls a subscript *sub.pl* which contains an exit criteria. When the criteria is met the program exit only the subscript but not the main script. How I have to change the code to stop the main script?

***main.pl***:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
    
my @list = qw (a b c);

foreach my $i (@list) {    
    my $cmd = "sub.pl $i";
    print "$cmd\n";        
    system($cmd);        
}
```

***sub.pl***:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;    
use Cwd;

my $dir0 = getcwd;    
open my $LOG, ">>$dir0/log.txt" or die "Cannot open log.txt: $!\n";

my $value = $ARGV[0];

if ( $value eq 'b') {
    print "\nExit from script 2\n";
    exit;
}

print $LOG "Value is $value\n";
close $LOG;
```

The STDOUT is:

```
# sub.pl a
# sub.pl b
# 
# Exit from script 2
# sub.pl c
```

And the $LOG output is:

```
# Value is a
# Value is c
```

I would like that the script stops at value *b*.

Comment: This is not a good way to run external code in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sub.pl is always exiting at the end of the script, not just when you exit explicitly exit somewhere else. You can exit with a specific code in sub.pl:

```
exit 1 if $value eq "b";
```

and then look for the exit code in main.pl:

```
system( $cmd ) and last
```

Comment: It works. I found out that also `system($cmd) and exit;` and `system($cmd) or die "Exit with die: $!\n";` works. At the moment I prefer _die_-method since it gives me an error.

Comment: Other comments: `system($cmd) == 0 and die "Exit with die: $?\n!";`  and `system($cmd) or die "Exit with die: $?\n!";`  gives the same STDOUT: `sub2.pl a` `Exit with die: 0` `! at main.pl line 15.` . `system($cmd) and die "Exit with die: $?\n!";`  and `system($cmd) == 0 or die "Exit with die: $?\n!";`  gives the same STDOUT: `sub2.pl a` `sub2.pl b` `Exit from script 2` `Exit with die: 256` `! at main.pl line 15.` Why in the first two cases there are two missing STDOUTs? It seems that in the first two cases the exit from main happens before the second loop happens. How this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @AKHolland's answer...

In general unfortunately can't just check the exit code of `system($cmd)` as perl makes life difficult by multiplexing a lot more information than just the exit code into `$?`. [1] I would recommend always using code like this to check it.

```perl
system($cmd);
last if ( ($? >> 8) & 255);
```

[1] https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system

Comment: I prefer to use the [exit status macros in the POSIX module](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX#WAIT) instead of magic numbers.